# EF CodeFirst Initializer - Unable to set PK values

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I'm doing a data migration of a small set of tables.  The keys are of course alinged in the source database and I have composed initialization statements similar to this one:

```
context.Countries.Add(new Country{CountryId=75,CountryName="US"});
context.Countries.Add(new Country{CountryId=89,CountryName="Argentina"});
```

However, when I look in the database afterwards I find this:

```
CountryID | CountryName
------------------------
1         | US
2         | Argentina
```

(It disregards the CountryIds I provide and uses n+1 values for this identity column.)

In an effort to solve the problem I tried this:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Set IDENTITY_INSERT COUNTRIES ON");            
GetCountries().ForEach(c=>context.Countries.Add(c));
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Set IDENTITY_INSERT COUNTRIES OFF");
```

But I see no difference in the keys in the db.

How do I do an Identity Insert from my Initializer's Seed() method?

EDIT:

I'm posting the results of my final attempt for the benefit of anyone else following after:

```
private void InsertCountries(SodContext context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Set IDENTITY_INSERT COUNTRIES ON");
        string cmd = "INSERT INTO COUNTRIES (CountryId,Name,IsActive) values ({0},'{1}',{2})";            
        GetCountries().ForEach(cntry=>context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format(cmd,cntry.CountryId,cntry.Name,cntry.IsActive==false?0:1)));            
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Set IDENTITY_INSERT COUNTRIES OFF");            
    }
```

However, I get the error message that I have to turn IDENTITY_INSERT ON.

I'm giving up and switching over to doing this in a TSQL script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have configured your primary key properties as database generated identities(ie: Auto increment) then EF will not include that column in the insert statements that are issued. So EF will request the generated key and update the primary key property.

What you can do is script the necessary data and execute that script directly without using entities.

Answer (score 0):

I had a go at what you were trying in the c# code. 
Putting everything in the same sql command statement does work.

```
const string sqlCmd = "set identity_insert [role] on insert into [role](id, name) values({0}, {1}) set identity_insert [role] off";

context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlCmd,(int)SystemRole.SuperAdministrator, superAdminRole);
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlCmd, (int)SystemRole.Administrator, adminRole);
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlCmd, (int)SystemRole.Manager, managerRole);
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlCmd, (int)SystemRole.User, userRole);
```